# Headers are read-only, when trying to SignIn with CookieAuthentication

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to create some cookie authentication, but gives me this exception:

`'Headers are read-only, response has already started.'`

To me it does not make any sense, beacuse i dont know when it sends and what it is trying to change..

I have this Method, that is handling the login where it will die at HttpContext.SignInAsync()

```
    private async Task TryLogin()
    {
        try
        {
            User user = Service.Login(User);

            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.UserData, user.UserID.ToString())
            };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Authentication"));
            var authProps = new AuthenticationProperties
            {
                IsPersistent = true,
                
            };

            StateHasChanged();


            await HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                claimsIdentity,
                authProps
            );

        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

This is what i have in my Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
    });

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

I dont remember what i have tried, but just know that it gives me the same exception everytime..

Comment: Don't DIY for authentication. You have a SPA now, HttpContext.SignInAsync() is for use on a  Server.

Comment: What should i use for Authentication then?
If i cannot use HttpContext.SignInAsync()..

Comment: Too much for an answer here.  The standard templates give you a few options, in net8 they will be improved. And plenty of articles about using Auth0 or AzAD etc.

Comment: Would a possible solution be to create and handle the sessions my self, and then just saving a sessionid (and the necesarry data) in the database and in a cookie? Or would that just be a stupid 'solution'?